# How do I implement "Cancel" button inside the method building data source in ModelController.m for Page View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a Page View Controller that's implemented in 3 files.  One of them, the ModelController.m implements "generateData" method, which basically just builds and formats all the pages for this Page View Controller.  Inside this method, the first thing I do is I create a Progress Bar popup with "Cancel" button.  Then, inside the while() loop, I keep building the pages and at the same time, every 10th page, I update the progress bar for the user to see that the application is still generating the output.

Once the "generateData" method completes, i.e. builds all the pages (and there may be over 1,000 or even 10,000 pages depending on user input), it returns "self" to a method inside RootViewController.m, which in turn passes that generated data in "dataObject" to "viewWillAppear" in DataViewController.m, which finally displays pages in that object to the user.

It all works great, except the "Cancel" button.  Because "generateData" method runs on the main thread, it blocks and the "Cancel" button becomes totally unresponsive.  By "blocks" I of course mean it takes all CPU cycles, not allowing anyting else to execute, and it may take over a minute to generate 10,000 pages so I really want to allow the user to cancel the operation.

I tried to create a separate thread for the Progress Bar popup which contains Cancel button, but that won't work because all UI operations need to be performed on the application's main thread.

What *almost* seems to work, is when I put the "generateData" method on a separate thread and keep the Progress Bar on the main thread.  This would work just fine, except that now "generateData" is put on another thread to execute in the background and returns immediately, hence returning empty "self" or rather empty "dataObject", causing a crash because there is nothing in that object yet to display.

So how can I check if the "generateData" thread is done, and "return self" ONLY when it's done?  I can't really have some BOOL true/false variable and do it in a loop, because that loop on the main thread would be again blocking the "Cancel" button.

Or, alternatively, what is the correct way to implement the "Cancel" button on a lengthy method in iOS?  Maybe I'm doing it all wrong, but for the life of me I can't find the right recipe for this.

Thank you in advance for the help, the code is rather extensive and that's why I didn't include any, but I hope my description gives you a good idea of what's going on.  I can provide code if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to load the data asynchronously (on a background thread) and update the main (UI) thread to update the progress bar, etc...  But you probably don't need a progress bar since you can probably load those pages faster than a user can flip them, so load 100 and let the user play while you continue to load the next 99,900...  Except those may not be the exact numbers you should use....

If you continue to use the progress view and cancel button, then you would cancel the background thread when the user presses "Cancel", which would respond since your data generation is on a background thread...

Look into either [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) or [NSInvocationOperations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Here's a good tutorial by Ray Wenderlich to get you started.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Like the idea to load first 100 pages and let user interact. I played with GCD and operation dependency but that didn't seem to work -- my "generateData" still returned immediately with an empty data object since I execute it on the background thread. For example:

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(generateData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
return self;

...it first puts "generateData" on a background thread, and then **immediately** returns self, with an empty dataObject. I'll look at what you suggested and post an update. Thanks!